Can I Run Azure Web App on Linux Without Docker?
We recently moved some node web apps running as App Services from Windows to Linux. In doing so we noticed the apps now get launched in a docker container.

The deploy is incredibly slow going from a bitbucket repo into a dockerized app. Like 30 minutes plus. Compare that to just a few minutes max on Windows.
I'm also finding that the container is recycled from time-to-time and/or aborted completely, destroyed and then restarted.

We're trying to get our arms around all of this so any relevant documentation links would be appreciated. Also, we're wondering if we can run the app on linux WITHOUT having it run in a container.

Your bitbucket pipeline is horrible and containers being recycled means you have a memory leak so docker is out-of-memory killing your app. these at least are not reasons to avoid Docker.

There is no bitbucket pipeline at work here.  Once there's a merge to master, the app gets deployed on a staging slot.   Azure controls the deployment containerization via oryx.
We've never seen any evidence of a memory leak, but noted.   Azure tells me they'll restart apps to pickup updates.   Here's a recent notification from the log: "Recycling app:  to process new updates.".   That doesn't indicate memory leak to me.

There's quite a bit of code and it's proprietary, so sharing it won't be possible.


Can I Run Azure Web App on Linux Without Docker?

Yes, you can deploy Web App to Azure App Service running on Linux.

In VSCode, you can deploy Node JS App to Azure Linux App Service.

In Portal, you can see the option to create Node App with Linux without any docker support.




I have tried to deploy the Node JS App from VSCode to the app created in Portal (shown above).


Output:


any relevant documentation links would be appreciated.

Also refer this blog by Alexey Baryshnikov  and MSDoc on how to run NodeJS Linux App Service without Docker.

I will take a look at the referenced docs.   I can tell you when I set up the web apps in the portal I did select Code as the Publish method.   However, as I've explained above, the Deployment Settings are tied to a branch in a bitbucket repo.   When there's a new commit, the code gets redeployed.   In Azure, the Oryx deployment system actually deploys it in a docker container.

How does your yml look.Did you try by changing the yml file?

No yml in our repo
